# show black when draw the skia rendering result in outside opengl environment

Tags: fbo, skia

I'm trying to draw the skia result into an FBO instead of directly drawing into the window frame buffer.
steps like below:
(1) create texture with fbo
(2) create SkSurface with the created fbo using SkSurfaces::WrapBackendRenderTarget
(3) draw using canvas in skia
(4) draw the created texture(in step 2) in outside opengl environment to the screen. but show black

after step 3, I dump the createed texture. the texture has the right content

the snap code is below, anyone can figure out the problem? thanks. I've been stuck for a few days

```
//initialize in render thread:
glfwMakeContextCurrent(native_window_);
int width = 800, height = 600;
sk_sp<const GrGLInterface> glInterface = GrGLMakeNativeInterface();
GrDirectContext* grDirectContext_ = GrDirectContexts::MakeGL(GrGLMakeNativeInterface(), GrContextOptions()).release();
shared_ptr<TextureData> g_texture = CITextureUtils::createTextureWithFBO(CIGLContext::getInstance(), width, height);
sk_sp<SkSurface> g_surface = SkSurfaces::WrapBackendRenderTarget(
        grDirectContext_,
        GrBackendRenderTargets::MakeGL(width,
                                        height,
                                        1,
                                        8,
                                        GrGLFramebufferInfo{(GrGLuint)g_texture->fbo, GL_RGBA8}),
        kBottomLeft_GrSurfaceOrigin,
        kRGBA_8888_SkColorType,
        nullptr,
        nullptr);

//the draw loop in render thread:

SkCanvas *canvas = g_surface->getCanvas();
canvas->clear(kClearColor);
                canvas->save();
                canvas->translate(SkIntToScalar(128), SkIntToScalar(128));
                canvas->rotate(SkIntToScalar(45));
                SkRect rect = SkRect::MakeXYWH(-90.5f, -90.5f, 181.0f, 181.0f);
                SkPaint paint;
                paint.setColor(SK_ColorBLUE);
                canvas->drawRect(rect, paint);
                canvas->restore();
grDirectContext_->flush();
grDirectContext_->resetContext();
// here dump the created texture, the texture has right context
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &lOldFbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, texture->fbo);
glReadPixels(0, 0, bitmap->width, bitmap->height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmap->plane[0]);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, lOldFbo);

// draw in outside opengl environment in render thread:

glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_texture->textureID);
GLint currProgram;
glGetIntegerv(GL_CURRENT_PROGRAM, &currProgram);
shader_.use();
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

glfwSwapBuffers((GLFWwindow*)window_);
```

I dump the created texture after the skia rendering, the texture has right content. but when rendering to the screen in outside opengl environment show black.